# Find element in Laravel object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

below is an output of my laravel object...

```
$my_array = Array( [0] => stdClass Object ( [From] => name1 [To] => name12 [Message] => hey) [1] => stdClass Object ( [From] => name13 [To] => name143 [Message] => byeeeeee)
```

I need to find `name12` is present or not without using `foreach loop`... how do i do this???I have tried...

```
if (in_array('name12', $my_array)) {
    echo "Match found";
}
else {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Comparing a string with an object isn't likely to give you a match; you should be comparing against the property of the object

Comment: yes @MarkBaker is right, and one more thing is `in_array` is only for 1D array. For searching in multi-dimensional, need to to loop over it and then check for `in_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if count(
    array_filter(
        $my_array,
        function($value) {
            return $value->From == 'name12';
        }
    ) > 0) {
    echo "Match found";
} else {
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two objects in the array ad the first two keys:

$my_array[0] and $my_array[1]

If you are sure that you know the number of items that there will be in the array then you can do something like this:

```
if(
$my_array[0]->From === 'name12' ||
$my_array[0]->To === 'name12' ||
$my_array[1]->From === 'name12' ||
$my_array[1]->To === 'name12'
){
  echo "Match found";
} else{
  echo "Match not found";
}
```